# Description for URL in Google Sitemap

Tags: sitemap

Is it possible to specify description for URL-element in Google Sitemaps?

Example (see description-tag):

```
<url>
  <loc>http://www.example.com/dogs</loc>
  <description>This page for dogs, you can find new products for dogs here.</description>
  <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
   <image:image>
    <image:loc>http://www.example.com/image.jpg</image:loc> 
  </image:image>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.example.com/cats</loc>
  <description>This page for cats, you can find new products for cats here.</description>
  <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
   <image:image>
    <image:loc>http://www.example.com/image.jpg</image:loc> 
  </image:image>
</url>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second the [support of Google for sitemaps](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183668) you can submit a RSS or atom file (a xml) like a sitemap.

In RSS or atom file you can to put a description for the url. You can read the [especification of RSS](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification)

An exemple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
 <title>RSS Title</title>
  <description>This is an example of an RSS feed</description>
  <link>http://www.someexamplerssdomain.com/main.html</link>
  <lastBuildDate>Mon, 06 Sep 2010 00:01:00 +0000 </lastBuildDate>
  <pubDate>Mon, 06 Sep 2009 16:45:00 +0000 </pubDate>
 <ttl>1800</ttl>

 <item>
  <title>Example entry</title>
  <description>Here is some text containing an interesting description.</description>
  <link>http://www.wikipedia.org/</link>
  <guid>unique string per item</guid>
  <pubDate>Mon, 06 Sep 2009 16:45:00 +0000 </pubDate>
 </item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Thank you, will look into RSS feeds!

Comment: I'm happy for can help you :D

Comment: @user2035638 Did the RSS feed `description` tag end up being respected and used by Google? Judging from [https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en) `description` is not something that is looked at for sitemaps.